# python convert unicode to readable character

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode

I am using python 2.7 and psycopg2 for connecting to postgresql

I read a bunch of data from a source which has strings like `'Aéropostale'`. I then store it in the database. However, in postgresql it is ending up as `'A\u00e9ropostale'`. But I want it to get stored as 'Aéropostale'.

The encoding of postgresql database is utf-8.

Please tell me how can I store the actual string 'Aéropostale' instead. 
I suspect that the problem is happening in python. Please advice.

EDIT:

Here is my data source

```
response_json = json.loads(response.json())
```

response is obtained via service call and looks like:

```
print(type(response.json())
>> <type'str'>
print(response.json())
>> {"NameRecommendation": ["ValueRecommendation": [{"Value": "\"Handmade\""}, { "Value": "Abercrombie & Fitch"}, {"Value": "A\u00e9ropostale"}, {"Value": "Ann Taylor"}}]
```

From the above data, my goal is to construct a list of all ValueRecommendation.Value and store in a postgresql json datatype column. So the python equivalent list that I want to store is

```
py_list = ["Handmade", "Abercrombie & Fitch",  "A\u00e9ropostale", "Ann Taylor"]
```

Then I convert py_list in to json representation using json.dumps()

```
json_py_list = json.dumps(py_list)
```

And finally, to insert, I use psycopg2.cursor() and mogrify()

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("connectionString")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(cursor.mogrify("INSERT INTO table (columnName) VALUES (%s), (json_py_list,)))
```

As I mentioned earlier, using the above logic, string with special charaters like è are getting stored as utf8 character code. 
 Please spot my mistake.

Comment: Where does the data come from? That looks like you either stored the `repr()` representation or the JSON encoding. Please show us your code.

Comment: Simply store the value. No further action is required so long as you're sending utf-8 data if the server is expecting utf-8 data. This isn't an encoding mismatch problem anyway. Something you're doing in the code you haven't shown us is creating the problem, you're transforming the data. It'd be useful to know some basics like the database driver you're using, but above all else, *show us the code*. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try converting your *latin1* string in *utf8* : `toStore = dataStr.decode('latin1').encode('utf8') if isinstance(dataStr,unicode) else dataStr.encode('utf8')`. They'll show up correctly in postgresql.

Comment: Friends, I have added some code snippets. Please take a look at my question again and help me.

Comment: You end up with `'A\u00e9ropostale'` in your database. this is not utf8 but either latin1 or cp1252. So you keep the original encoding of your string. what's the issue then ?? do you want to convert those into utf8 so that they'll show up correctly in a database viewer ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to show up properly in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps` escapes non-ASCII characters by default so its output can work in non-Unicode-safe environments. You can turn this off with:

```
json_py_list = json.dumps(py_list, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Now you will get UTF-8-encoded bytes (unless you change that too with `encoding=`) so you'll need to make sure your database connection is using that encoding.

In general it shouldn't make any difference as both forms are valid JSON and even with `ensure_ascii` off there are still characters that get `\u`-encoded.